# Joomla 3.2 page goes blank after installing jkefel extensions

Tags: joomla, crash

i have setup joomla 3.2 version, and i also have migrate my old website from joomla 1.5 to joomla 3.2 using JUpgrade tools, everything was fine at the beginning, all content was there, just need a few arrangement, in order to re-arranged a few page n article, i need some tabbing function, and i've search in extensions.joomla.org and i have found jkefel from jproven.com, i've download it and try to install it, then suddenly the page(site and administrator) goes blank. Do anyone know how to fix this? or how to rollback if there is any instead of setting up back from the beginning??...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

==> Go to your site's database ==> #__extensions table.

==> find entries for that extension.

==> set published to '0' for all(if more then one).

By doing this, that extension will stop working and your site will up again.

==> Now go to Global Configuration of your site.

==> set debug to yes and Error reporting to 'Maximum'.

==> Go to Extension manager and enable extension again and try to browse your site.

==> Now you are able to see all issues of that extension.